# Why can my external visitor access the 'Integrate' option in the Sharepoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, powerapp

My external visitor can see the 'Integrate' options (Power Apps, Power BI, Power Automate) in the drop down in a library, they can also access the apps! They don't have access to other areas 0f SharePoint such as Site or Library Settings etc. How is this possible?

[image: Visitor View of a library]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the user has license to Power Apps, BI and Automate in their M365 environment!

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.